# Using view_as_windows and numpy.ma.median on a masked image

Tags: python, image, scikit-image

I'm trying to filter an image so that the value of each pixel is equal to the value of the median of the pixels within a 50x50 square around it, excluding any masked pixels. This is my latest attempt:

1. Read an image from a FITS file (looks like this...)
   [image]
2. Apply a mask from another FITS file
3. Pass a 50x50 pixel window (I think this is the best way to do it...open to suggestions) across the masked image (masked image below)
   [image]
4. Create a filtered copy of the masked image, with the value of each pixel being equal to the value of the median of the pixels within a 50x50 square around it, excluding any masked pixels

In the code here, I've used some methods from the documentation of [skimage.util.view_as_windows](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows)
to produce the filtered image:
[image]

It looks to me like it's ignoring the masked pixels. My question is twofold:
Is this the best way to do it?
If so, why does it look like it's ignoring the mask?

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

#   Use the fits files as input image and mask
hdulist = fits.open('xbulge-w1.fits')
image = hdulist[0].data
hdulist3 = fits.open('xbulge-mask.fits')
mask = 1 - hdulist3[0].data
imagemasked = np.ma.masked_array(image, mask = mask)

side = 50
window_shape = (side, side)

Afiltered = view_as_windows(imagemasked, window_shape)

# collapse the last two dimensions in one
flatten_view = Afiltered.reshape(Afiltered.shape[0], Afiltered.shape[1], -1)

# resampling the image by taking median
median_view = np.ma.median(flatten_view, axis=2)
```

Note: Using 'side = 50' results in quite a long run-time, so for testing purposes I've tended to decrease it to, say 10 to 25.

Comment: skimage dosnot support for masking, https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2763#issuecomment-323850537

Answer (score 0):

there are many  filters in python with different behavior by nan's, for example for mean filter:

```
x=np.array([[0.1,0.8,.2],
            [0.5,0.2,np.nan],
            [0.7,0.2,0.9],
            [0.4,0.7,1],
            [np.nan,0.14,1]])

print(uniform_filter(x, size=3, mode='constant'))

[[ 0.17777778         nan         nan]
 [ 0.27777778         nan         nan]
 [ 0.3                nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan         nan]]
```

or

```
from skimage.filters.rank import mean
from skimage.morphology import square
from skimage import img_as_float
x=np.array([[0.1,0.8,.2],
        [0.5,0.2,np.nan],
        [0.7,0.2,0.9],
        [0.4,0.7,1],
        [np.nan,0.14,1]])

print(mean(x, square(3)))

[[102  76  76]
 [106 102  97]
 [114 130 127]
 [ 90 142 167]
 [ 79 137 181]]

print(img_as_float(mean(x, square(3))))

[[ 0.4         0.29803922  0.29803922]
 [ 0.41568627  0.4         0.38039216]
 [ 0.44705882  0.50980392  0.49803922]
 [ 0.35294118  0.55686275  0.65490196]
 [ 0.30980392  0.5372549   0.70980392]]
```

skimage dose not support nan's and masking: [refrence](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2763#issuecomment-323850537)
or

```
import numpy as np
# from scipy.signal import convolve
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

x=np.array([[0.1,0.8,.2],
            [0.5,0.2,np.nan],
            [0.7,0.2,0.9],
            [0.4,0.7,1],
            [np.nan,0.14,1]])

core = np.full((3,3),1/3**2)

# convolve(x, core, mode='same')
convolve2d(x, core, mode='same')

[[ 0.17777778         nan         nan]
 [ 0.27777778         nan         nan]
 [ 0.3                nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan  0.43777778]
 [        nan         nan  0.31555556]]
```

Comment: I've tried so many different permutations, that I'm getting the distinct impression that the task isn't possible using Python. Can it actually be done with existing modules and packages? Or do I have to write my own??? maybe I should study computer science, rather than astronomy :(